# Find Missing Dates Between Two Dates

Tags: java

I got a list of dates as String 
for example date1->'11-11-2010' and date2->'12-01-2011'
I want to print all the dates between these two dates..
I tried to work with cal.add() but am not able to set my date1 to my cal.. if i do so i get null p

Answer (score 3):

below code should do the trick for you.

```
    String date1 = "11-11-2010";
    String date2 = "12-01-2011";

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar1.setTime(format.parse(date1));

    Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar2.setTime(format.parse(date2));

    Date currentDate = calendar1.getTime();
    while(!currentDate.equals(cal2.getTime())){
        calendar1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        currentDate = cal1.getTime();
        System.out.println(currentDate);

    }
```

Comment: Infinite loop for date2 < date1 situation.

Comment: Ofcourse it is not a complete solution. you could switch the 2 variables as fromDate and toDate to not let that happen.